# ews resolvename to get all contacts

Tags: c#, exchange-server

In Exchange service, using ResolveName(String) method I am able to get all the contacts matching the name that was passed as a parameter.

How I can get all the contacts (Global Contact List) from Exchange service using c#?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct access to the Global Address List in EWS. To get that information you'd need to access the Active Directory, either using LDAP or PowerShell.